Dueling Arbitration Agreements
Say I sign up for a new and exciting service from the American Association of Arbitrators. For $20.00 a month, they will arbitrate as many disputes for me as I want. All I have to do is to agree to use them as my exclusive arbitration organization, and have them arbitrate all disputes that I initiate (other than with that organization), instead of taking them to court.
Then I sign another contract with, say, Disney, which has an arbitration provision that says all disputes with them will be arbitrated exclusively by the American Arbitration Association, not to be confused with the American Association of Arbitrators. This is fine as long as there isn't actually a dispute.
Now, say Disney comes to my house and kills my tree. Now I have a dispute with Disney, and being a fool, I file it in civil court. Immediately, the American Association of Arbitrators tries to present the court with my agreement with them, asking to compel me to arbitrate through them, and Disney tries to present the court with my agreement with them, asking the court to compel me to arbitrate through the American Arbitration Association.
Who, if anyone, ends up settling my dispute? Does one party here lack some kind of standing to compel arbitration? Do I owe damages to anyone for signing mutually exclusive contracts and depriving someone of an arbitration case or other thing I promised them? Is the dispute just contracted out of existence since there's no valid way to bring it?

If you want a remedy for a wrong by Disney within the scope of a valid arbitration clause that you agreed to with Disney, you must bring the claim according to the terms of that arbitration clause.
Doing so may place you in breach of another contract you have, such as an "arbitrate-everything-with-us" agreement with some arbitrator.1
You are generally allowed to breach contracts. The other party's remedy is normally money damages. This is the theory behind "efficient breach."
Courts are reluctant to compel performance through the equitable remedy known as specific performance.
If you have entered into contracts with conflicting obligations, you need to choose which to breach.
If, in order to get something out of Contract #1, you have to breach Contract #2, you have to choose if you would like to make that breach.
As far as terminology goes, you have not described dueling arbitration agreements. An arbitration agreement is an agreement between two parties to have their disputes resolved by arbitration, often also specifying the forum. There is only one of those in your example: the agreement with Disney.
The other agreement is an exclusive service agreement.
If one attempted to resolve a dispute with Disney by unilaterally bringing the dispute to an arbitrator that Disney did not agree to, it would just have no effect on Disney.

1. You don't even need to stipulate an arbitration clause with Disney. The moment you make this agreement with an exclusive arbitrator, there are likely many disputes with many parties for which the only way to bring them to litigation would be in violation of the exclusive "arbitrate all disputes with us" clause. For one thing, most people you interact with are not in a contractual relationship with you, let alone one that includes their agreement to let you bring them into arbitration. For most people, your disputes with them would have to be in court. I have never seen such an agreement.
